# Embed Apache ZooKeeper in Jetty generates Debug log message

Tags: log4j, jetty, apache-zookeeper

I am using Jetty 8 and ZooKeeper 3.4.5. When I connect to ZooKeeper, jetty keep generating DEBUG level message. How to suppress it?

```
16:54:56.757 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:56.758 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:56.758 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:56.759 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:56.760 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:56.760 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x13ddc6e9a2b000c after 3ms
16:54:56.760 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.424 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.425 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.425 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.426 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.427 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG o.a.z.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient - Could not retrieve login configuration: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
16:54:58.427 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x13ddc6e9a2b000c after 2ms
```

I added log4j.properties under src folder:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r - [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper=INFO
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked again my included library, and I found out that LogBack was included. I think JVM load logback instead of log4j. Once I supply logback.xml, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in config should help:

```
<logger name="com.apache.zookeeper" level="info">
   <!-- appenders -->
</logger>
```

Comment: Thanks, which file should I modify? Where is this file?

Comment: you should modify log4j config, there are many ways to do it http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: i mean, where is the location of the file? In zookeeper folder? or in Jetty folder? or in eclipse folder (I am using eclipse for development)?

Comment: You should create it in your project

Comment: I have added log4j.properties. Still no luck.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that logback.jar was in the same folder, and I think it override log4j.jar