# How to mute apache zookeeper debug messages (AWS EMR)?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-zookeeper, elastic-map-reduce, mute

How to mute DEBUG messages on AWS Elastic MapReduce Master node?

```
hbase(main):003:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                               
mydb                                                                                                                
1 row(s) in 0.0510 seconds

hbase(main):004:0> 00:25:17.104 [main-SendThread(ip-172-31-14-206.ec2.internal:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x1493a5c3b78001b after 1ms

hbase(main):005:0* 00:26:17.165 [main-SendThread(ip-172-31-14-206.ec2.internal:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Got ping response for sessionid: 0x1493a5c3b78001b after 1ms
```

Comment: Murat, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is some option in Web UI to change log verbosity.
But there must be a Zookeeper (which is using Log4j) configuration folder **${ZOOKEEPER_HOME}/conf** where you can edit file **logj4.properties** and specify:

```
zookeeper.console.threshold=WARN
```

But I think that those changes must be done not directly in Zookeeper, but in HBase log configuration -**${HBASE_HOME}/conf** (HBase also use Log4j), because HBase can manage Zookeeper.
There are few parameters that can be edited there:

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hbase.root.logger=INFO,console
hbase.security.logger=INFO,console

# Main log level
log4j.threshold=ALL

# Zookeeper log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO
```

To find this file you can try next command:

```
$ find /* -name "log4j.properties" | grep -E "zookeeper|hbase"
/hadoop/zookeeper/conf/log4j.properties
/hadoop/hbase/conf/log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846789/embed-apache-zookeeper-in-jetty-generates-debug-log-message) helps to suppress debug log messages not only for the `hbase shell` but for all other hbase running daemons (e.g. region server, zookeeper). All you need is to add:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

into `~/hbase/conf/logback.xml` and restart all services or hbase shell.